# How to obtain the Gordian achievement in Zen Bound 2?

Tags: achievements, zen-bound-2

The description reads "Blindly refuse defeat", which is about as clear as mud.  What do I need to do to earn this achievement?

Comment: Like Alexander the Great and the Gordian Knot, you have to cut your iPhone in half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To gain the Gordian achievement you need to finish a level having used all the available rope.
When you do so you end up with something looking more or less like a knot.

As celion pointed out, this is a reference to Alexander and the Gordian Knot.

Comment: And then manage to tie it off?  I've unspooled all the rope once or twice, but never managed to tie the rope off at the same time.

Comment: @Margaret Yes, you must still manage to tie it off, it takes some trial and error but it's definitely possible.

Comment: Achieved!  Huzzah!

Comment: This is very easily achieved on the very first level. I got this achievement without realizing that you don't have to use up all the rope.